# C Programming fwrite on full drive

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, fwrite

What happens to fwrite if it the drive is full? Assuming that it was compiled on a windows machine with visual studio.

Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering if there would be a stall or if it would just continue

Comment: "a stall"? I'm not sure what you're thinking of. The question is whether it will return an error condition. Contrary to the accepted answer, it won't because the data is buffered, first by stdio and second by the OS. In order to see the error you have to force the data to disk (fflush isn't enough because it only flushes the stdio buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a write cannot be performed, `fwrite()` either returns a short item count (if some items have been written before an error occurred) or `0`. `fwrite()` does not block if an error occurs. To differentiate and end-of-file condition from an IO error, use the `feof()` and `ferror()` functions.

Comment: Can `fwrite` encounter an end-of-file condition? Or is it only `fread`? (I imagine it's possible in rare cases, like if you try to write past the end of /dev/sda (don't test that, btw))

Comment: @immibis `fwrite()` can encounter an end-of-file condition under certain conditions (e.g. writing to a block-device and encountering its end) but it's rare.

Comment: Actually, nothing happens because the output is buffered and the system doesn't find out until later that the disk is full, so no error is returned by `fwrite`.

Comment: @FUZxxl That's not an EOF condition, it's a short write. fwrite will never set feof.

Comment: @JimBalter A short write can be an EOF condition as far as I know.

Comment: @FUZxxl "as far as I know" is an expression of ignorance. I just *told* you that it's not an EOF condition, so you *should* now know that it isn't. Here's what the C standard says: "EOF
which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream". Do you know what "input" is, and what "fwrite" does? Sheesh.

Comment: Since `fwrite()` can buffer the content the failure may not be immediately apparent.  Thus the return value from [`fflush()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx)) or [`fclose()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) ([MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxfsw25t.aspx)) must also be checked for errors.  Read the man pages/MSDN documents..